# Doubt on L Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am having a doubt in L Hopital's rule. That is, if we are having some three functions which are reducing to $\frac00$ like
$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^{1/2}$$ 
Here $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ reduces to $\frac00$ but here there is a power function ($\frac12$ in our case). So my question is can we apply L Hopital's rule only for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by ignoring the power function or should we include it in our differentiation?

I tried to find on internet but didn't get my answer, please explain.

I proved his will be a bonus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have

$$\lim_{x \to a} \left( {\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}\right)^{1\over 2}$$

you can move the limit inside since $x^{1\over 2}$ is a continious function.

$$\lim_{x \to a} \left( {\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}\right)^{1\over 2} =  \left( {\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}\right)^{1\over 2}$$

If you now can apply L'Hospital on the inner limit it is still valid for the whole expression.